# I made a project using python that detects an object in an image, but I need to do GUI for the input/output

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, user-interface, image-processing, tkinter

```
    `import cv2
    import numpy as np

import time
from tkinter import * 
import os
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
cv2.setUseOptimized(True)
cv2.useOptimized()
x1 = cv2.getTickCount()
model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow("frozen_inference_graph.pb","ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29.pbtxt")
classNames = {0:'background',1:'person',2:'bicycle',3:'car',7:'train'                               
              ,13:'stop sign',17:'cat',18:'dog',44:'bottle',48:'fork',49:'knife',                        
              51:'bowl',53:'apple',55:'orange',73:'laptop', 
              77: 'cell phone',78: 'microwave',79:'oven',80:'toaster'}

#image = cv2.imread("fork1.jpg")
def browse_image():
    global folder_path
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    img = str(os.path.basename(filename))
    return img
x=browse_image()
print(x)         
image = cv2.imread(x)   
root = Tk()
folder_path = StringVar()
lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=folder_path)
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button2 = Button(text="Browse",command=browse_image)
button2.grid(row=0, column=3)


image = cv2.resize(image,(300,300))
image = cv2.medianBlur(image, 5)
w,h,_ = image.shape
model.setInput(cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, size = (w,h), swapRB=True))
output = model.forward()


def id_class_name(class_id, classes):
    for key, value in classes.items():
        if class_id == key:
            return value

for detection in output[0, 0, :, :]:
    confidence = detection[2]
    if confidence > 0.5:
        class_id = detection[1]
        class_name = id_class_name(class_id,classNames)

        #If the object doesnt match a one in the dataset or its skewed
        if class_name == None or class_name == "background":
            print("unable to define")
        else:  
            print(class_name)

x2 = cv2.getTickCount()
t = (x2-x1)/cv2.getTickFrequency()
print(t)
```

So this is my code I'm trying to detect the object in the image that I choose from the path with using another *files.py* to support this code to run, but I want the output to be shown in the GUI window with it's file name/image.jpeg instead of being printed on the terminal.

My question is how can I get the output of this code into the GUI window instead of having the Output on terminal?

Comment: Welcome, but what is your question? Please see [ask].

Comment: my question is how can i get the output of this code into the GUI window instead of having the Output on terminal??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples such as the one at https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html are good places to start when producing code. In this case, I've used this very example since you evidently want to put your widgets on a grid.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

from tkinter import filedialog
import os

def browse_image(*args):
    global folder_path
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    img = str(os.path.basename(filename))
    pic.set(img)
    return img

root = Tk()
root.title("Tina Gh")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

pic = StringVar()
pic.set('')

ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=pic).grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Do it", command=browse_image).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Path").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

root.bind('<Return>', browse_image)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you so much this worked for me but only for the image name /image.jpeg , but what i am actually looking for was to do the same but for the detected object name which is named as value in Id_class_name() this function returns the name of the detected object " value" . so how can i do the same you did but for this returned value ??

Comment: I'm sorry, where does Id_class_name come from? (I'm unfamiliar with this.)

Comment: In _my_ code, notice that the Python variable `pic` is associated with a `ttk.Label` object so that when `pic` is `set` the text displayed in the label changes. Therefore, you can replace `print` statements in your code with `pic.set`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you just want to show the name of the detected object in the image. You could do this just by showing text on a Tkinter window. This can be done using the Tkinter text widget, which can be created using the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, height=2, width=10) # height and width can be changed to suit your needs
text.pack()
text.insert(tk.END, "Your text here") # put text in the text widget
tk.mainloop()
```

If you would like to format, color or otherwise change the appearance of the text or place it in specific positions, check out the Tkinter documentation, available [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter), or [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html)

Comment: thank you for helping but this did not work for me , but as u said i want to show the name of the detected object, and when i added the code you gave me it shows me a text of what is wrote inside " your text here" , but i want it to show me the name of the detected object which is the main output of all this code.

Comment: maybe i dont know where to place the code correctly within the script

Comment: You need to pass the name of the detected object to the `text.insert()` function where it says `"Your text here"`. In fact, you could show more info using the same code, such as the file path.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow!

Try this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from tkinter import * 
import os
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *


cv2.setUseOptimized(True)
cv2.useOptimized()
x1 = cv2.getTickCount()
model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow("frozen_inference_graph.pb","ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29.pbtxt")
classNames = {0:'background',1:'person',2:'bicycle',3:'car',7:'train'                               
              ,13:'stop sign',17:'cat',18:'dog',44:'bottle',48:'fork',49:'knife',                        
              51:'bowl',53:'apple',55:'orange',73:'laptop', 
              77: 'cell phone',78: 'microwave',79:'oven',80:'toaster'}

#image = cv2.imread("fork1.jpg")


def browse_image():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    img = str(os.path.basename(filename))
    lbl1.config(text=img)
    lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    return img


x=browse_image()
print(x)
image = cv2.imread(x)   
root = Tk()
lbl1 = Label(root)
button2 = Button(text="Browse", command=browse_image)
button2.grid(row=0, column=3)


image = cv2.resize(image,(300,300))
image = cv2.medianBlur(image, 5)
w,h,_ = image.shape
model.setInput(cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, size = (w,h), swapRB=True))
output = model.forward()
canvas = Label(gui, image=output)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)


def id_class_name(class_id, classes):
    for key, value in classes.items():
        if class_id == key:
            return value

for detection in output[0, 0, :, :]:
    confidence = detection[2]
    if confidence > 0.5:
        class_id = detection[1]
        class_name = id_class_name(class_id,classNames)

        #If the object doesnt match a one in the dataset or its skewed
        if class_name == None or class_name == "background":
            print("unable to define")
        else:  
            print(class_name)

x2 = cv2.getTickCount()
t = (x2-x1)/cv2.getTickFrequency()
print(t)
```

Comment: thank you for helping but i dont know why i get NameError for gui it says " canvas = Label (gui, image=output) "  NameError : name "gui" is not defined

Comment: i missed the above section , but now i am getting a new error says " lbl1.config(text=img) " NameError : name "lbl1" is not defined